# how to create object tree from string in java script

Tags: javascript

Hi In javascript I have to create object tree from a string as below

"group1:node1:properties,group1:node2:properties,group2:node2:properties,group2:node3:properties,group2:node1:properties,group3:node2:properties".

In this, properties are also : seperated,

I require object tree as below

```
group1
   node1
     properties
   node2
     properties
group2
   node2
     properties
   node3
     properties
   node1
     properties
group3
   node2
     properties
```

can any body tell me what is the best way to do that with example.

Comment: I hope your teacher won't see this :-P

Comment: Do you need real objects or only an output?

Comment: I need to create object from which I can access on basis of group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it seems like a school exercise...I think you need to take a look at the split() method. First split on the comma (,), then the colon (:). For example..

Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/T852c/

```
var str = 'group1:node1:properties,group1:node2:properties,group2:node2:properties,group2:node3:properties,group2:node1:properties,group3:node2:properties';

var result ={},
    groups = str.split(','),
    groupsCount = groups.length; 

for(var i=groupsCount; i--;){
    var groupStr = groups[i],
        split = groupStr.split(':'),
        groupKey = split[0],
        nodeKey = split[1],
        properties = split[2],
        group = result[groupKey] || (result[groupKey] = {}),
        node = group[nodeKey] || (group[nodeKey] = {});
    
    node[properties] = { foo: 'bar' };    
}

console.log(result);
```

It might not be exactly what you are looking for but it might help to get you started. Good luck!

Comment: And when you splitted them, append to the array.